# Vertically center image that's not affected by KeyboardAwareScrollView in React Native

Tags: react-native

Alright, so this has got me busy for quite a few hours already. I am trying to create a login screen where the main components are rendered on the bottom, with the logo in the remaining space. This is kind of what I would like to achieve:

[image: desired result]

To support my textinputs, I use KeyboardAwareScrollView, as it works better for me as opposed to KeyboardAvoidingView. My code currently looks like this (I plan on using a background image with a 50% color overlay rather than the red background, so the ImageBackground has to stay in place too):

```
  <ImageBackground
    source={require('./assets/img/background-clouds.png')}
    resizeMode="cover"
    style={styles.backgroundImage}>
    <View style={styles.backgroundOverlay} />
    <View style={styles.dummyView}>
      <Text>elloha</Text>
    </View>
    <Image
      source={require('./assets/img/logo.png')}
      style={styles.backgroundLogo}
      resizeMode="contain"
    />
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
      keyboardOpeningTime={0}
      alwaysBounceHorizontal={false}
      alwaysBounceVertical={false}
      contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      extraScrollHeight={30}
      enableOnAndroid>
      <StatusBar
        backgroundColor="transparent"
        barStyle="light-content"
        hidden={false}
        translucent
      />
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}
        accessible={false}>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <View style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0 }} />

            <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
              <View style={styles.loginScreen}>
                // textinputs and buttons go here
              </View>
              <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
                position: 'absolute',
                width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                top: Dimensions.get('window').height,
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  </ImageBackground>
```

Relevant styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
  },
  backgroundContainer: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    flex: 1,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
  },
  backgroundOverlay: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  logoContainer: {
    top: "10%",
    width: "100%",
  },
  backgroundLogo: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    width: 126,
    height: 96,
  },
  dummyView: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    flex: 1,
  },
  loginContainer: {
    borderTopEndRadius: 30,
    borderTopStartRadius: 30,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    height: 500,
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingTop: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.1,
  },
  loginScreen: {
    width: "80%",
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
});
```

This yields the following result:

[image: current result]

I can get it done by adding `top: 160` to the backgroundLogo style, but that's a fixed value. I want it to be always in the center of the available space, but I'm unable to add a view between the background and the loginContainer, as all the logic for the keyboard and such is handled in between.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? Ideally, I should also be able to check the available height, and only show the logo if there is enough space (e.g. available height > 100, otherwise don't show logo).

Important:
I want the logo to stay fixed, so if the keyboard is shown, the logo should not move up. The loginContainer should go "over" the logo

EDIT:
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you show when the keyboard is opened view? please

Comment: Hi @RizwanAtta! I have added the screenshots to the original post. Note, this is an example with top: 160, so the logo is in place for this screen size as I would like it to be.

Comment: did the answer below not help?

Comment: @RizwanAtta no. The given answers allocate certain space to the different elements, e.g. 70% for the login container and 30% for the background + logo, which is not what I am looking for. I specifically want the login container to get the necessary height, whether it be 20% or 80% of the total height (e.g. if there is only one button in the login container, the height would more realistically be only 20% of the screen height), and the logo should be positioned in the center of the remaining height. So it should work dynamically, which is not what I have received as an answer just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Image inside a View with this style and give the loginContainer style height: '70%' :

```
      ...
      <View style={styles.dummyView}>
        <Text>elloha</Text>
      </View>

      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          height: '30%',
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '100%',
        }}>
      <Image
        source={require('./assets/img/logo.png')}
        style={styles.backgroundLogo}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
     </View>
     
     <KeyboardAwareScrollView
       keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
       ...


       ...
       loginContainer: {
         borderTopEndRadius: 30,
         borderTopStartRadius: 30,
         width: '100%',
         backgroundColor: 'orange',
         height: '70%',
         alignItems: 'center',
         paddingTop: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.1,
       },
       ...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Hamed: thank you for the input, I tried the above, but it renders the logo centered vertically and horizontally across the entire screen. So it is now hidden behind the "bottomsheet" by default, I want it to be shown in the red space available on top, and centered vertically in there.

Comment: @PennyWise: I change the solution, hope it works for you

Comment: @Hamed, that won't work for me. You now define 30% and 70% of the size, which I don't want, because on small screens I will end up with a scrollview for my sign up form, which would not be needed if the other 30% would suffice to show the entire "bottomsheet" login view. I want it to be dynamic, not defined by percentages.

Comment: @PennyWise, use Dimensions instead of percentages

Comment: @Hamed how would that work exactly? I want the login container to take up the exact amount of space, so it would have padding around the labels and inputfields, but not have any more space. In your example, there is too much space on the bottom, below the inputfields. I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

hie! I think using Dimension to get a specific screen's height and deciding it has 70% of the screen covered via form sheet and rest is free for a logo to be in and we can ask it to be down a little using rest of height's 50% as margin-top ( the image will be in the center of that image )

here is a SNACK [LINK](https://snack.expo.dev/@rizwan_atta/gnarly-chocolates) to see your example working with my suggested solution.

here is the draft code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, ImageBackground,TextInput,
Image, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, SafeAreaView, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import {KeyboardAwareScrollView} from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={{
        uri: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/08/23/18/37/tea-6568547_960_720.jpg',
      }}
      resizeMode="cover"
      style={styles.backgroundImage}>
      <View style={styles.backgroundOverlay} />
      <Image
        source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')}
        style={styles.backgroundLogo}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
        keyboardOpeningTime={0}
        alwaysBounceHorizontal={false}
        alwaysBounceVertical={false}
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        extraScrollHeight={30}
        enableOnAndroid>
        <StatusBar
          backgroundColor="transparent"
          barStyle="light-content"
          hidden={false}
          translucent
        />
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <View style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
              <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 0}} />

              <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
                <View style={styles.loginScreen}>
                <TextInput value={'email'} style={{borderBottomWidth:1, padding:10}}/>
                <TextInput value={'password'} style={{borderBottomWidth:1, padding:10}}/>
                </View>
                <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}} />
              </View>
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                  height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
                  position: 'absolute',
                  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                  top: Dimensions.get('window').height,
                }}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
  backgroundContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    flex: 1,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
  backgroundOverlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  logoContainer: {
    top: '10%',
    width: '100%',
  },
  backgroundLogo: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: Dimensions.get('window').height/7, // top for rest of the screen to push logo down
    width: 126,
    height: 96,
  },
  dummyView: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    flex: 1,
  },
  loginContainer: {
    borderTopEndRadius: 30,
    borderTopStartRadius: 30,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height/1.5, //container of form height
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.1,
  },
  loginScreen: {
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
});
```

**Here is the output of code on android/ios:**

[image: Here is the output of code on android/ios]